# add non databound column to gridview programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add a column to the gridview on page_load()

Its a label that I want to add. My datasource has ID in it.. but I dont want to display Id, I have to look up the ID in my object model and replace it with name.

So, I need a label like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="1234" runat="server" OnDataBinding="BindName" />
```

This is something I am doing in the ascx file.. inside TemplateField.

I want to do the same thing in the code behind programatically.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a class that implements that ITemplate interface.

```
public class TemplateImplementation : ITemplate
{
    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        Label label = new Label();
        label.DataBinding += Label_DataBinding;
        container.Controls.Add(label);
    }
    void Label_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label label = (Label)sender;
        object dataItem = DataBinder.GetDataItem(label.NamingContainer);
        string sName = /* Lookup your name using the dataitem here here */;
        label.Text = sName;
    }
}
```

You then create a TemplateColumn and set your ItemTemplate to an instance of this class.

```
TemplateColumn lblColumn = new TemplateColumn();
lblColumn.ItemTemplate = as;
grdMyGrid.Columns.Add(lblColumn);
```

Comment: Thanks all for help and solution.

Comment: @Mike J what is the `as` in `lblColumn.ItemTemplate = as;` here ?

Comment: @Bishan That should be 

`lblColumn.ItemTemplate = new TemplateImplementation();`

Also, for a GridView, you need to create a TemplateField, not TemplateColumn. TemplateColumns are for DataGrids.

Comment: @MikeJ how can i add `Label` into existing `TemplateField` in a `GridView` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an event for the GridView called RowDataBound.  Use that. Have a TemplateColumn in your markup for this column.  In the RowDataBound event, do something like this (crude example):

```
      Private Sub GridView1_OnRowDataBound(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs)
           If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
              'in this example the column in question is the 3rd column
              'unless you are doing some javascript or some css on the label, I would 
              'recommend using a literal and not label.  This is presuming there is no               
              'label or literal control in the ItemTemplate property of the TemplateColumn
              Dim lt as New Literal
              lt.Text = NameController.GetName(e.Row.DataItem("NameID")) 'your business logic layer goes here
              e.Row.Cells(2).Controls.Add(lt)
           End If
        End Sub
```

[In addition, here is a link that may help you further:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

ASPX Source

```
 <asp:GridView ID="sampleGridView" Runat="server" DataSourceID="sampleDataSource">
    <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Territories">
        <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="1234" runat="server"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="FirstName" DataField="FirstName" 
           SortExpression="FirstName"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="LastName" DataField="LastName" 
           SortExpression="LastName"></asp:BoundField>
</Columns>
```

C# Code

```
void sampleGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    Label bl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("1234");
    bl.Text= ((DataRowView) e.Row.DataItem)["ID"].ToString();
  }
}
```