# Custom or dynamically binding data to GridView control

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, .net-4.5

ASP.NET using C# with .NET F/W 3.5

Hi,
What are the best possibilities and easiest ways of adding Template columns(Textboxes) in Gridview by code?
While adding columns need to handle alignment and properties, Datatype etc.

What are the best ways and are there any NEW features with .NET Framework 3.5 or 4.0 or 4.5 in relates to custom or dynamic Data binding to Gridview control??

Please provide various solution in most of the ways?

Answer (score 2):

Check this SO thread to see how to add template columns:
[Programmatically add template columns to gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375843/programmatically-add-template-columns-to-gridview)

Creating custom templates for alignment etc, check these:
[add non databound column to gridview programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652148/add-non-databound-column-to-gridview-programmatically)
[How to create template columns dynamically in a grid view](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/create_template_columns.aspx)
[Creating Web Server Control Templates Dynamically](http://www.webswapp.com/codesamples/aspnet20/itemplate/gridview.aspx)
[Create Templated ASP.NET User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6.aspx)

To know about the new updates about frameworks, follow the msdn. A link is below about netfx 4.0, this have some information regarding data binding changes etc:
[What's New in the .NET Framework 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868.aspx) - Check the Data Section